# Split cell to fill two textboxes

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, cell

I made a userform which contains two textboxes. When I click the button, the two textboxes are unified in a single cell.

```vb
Dim Dados As String, DadosLen As Integer
With Me
    Dados = .caixanfnum.Text & Chr(10) & .caixanfdata.Text
    DadosLen = Len(.caixanfnum.Text)
End With
With Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4)
    .Font.Bold = False
    .WrapText = True
    .Value = Dados
    .Characters(1, DadosLen).Font.Bold = True
End With
```

I want to bring it back to the userform (I'm trying to make a search tool).

How do I split this cell to fill the two textboxes?

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php

Comment: Maybe `Split(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4).Value,Chr(10))` and read them back to each TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

For your problem the split function should be the best solution, but you need a delimiter. The delimiter is the character at wich position the string (value of the cell) will be splitted.

```
splitted_text = Split(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4).Value, "your character")
```

This will return an array. You get the parts of the splitted string with `splitted_text(0)` and `splitted_text(1)`

Another way wich could work are the `left`, `mid` and `right` functions.
This will only work if the strings you are combining in the cell have a constant length.

```
first_string=Left(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4).Value, 5)
second_string=Right(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4).Value, 5)
middle_string=Mid(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4).Value, 5,5)
```

First string will return the 5 left chars of the string in the cell, second_string will return the 5 last chars in the string. The middle_string will give you five chars starting at the 5. position in the string, so it will give you char 5-9.

Comment: Oh. You also had the same idea. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

You could,

1. Use the [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function, or
2. Use the [`Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function), [`Right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function), and [`Len`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/len-function) Functions

---

### 1. `Split`

```
Dim TempSplit AS Variant
TempSplit = Split(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4), Chr(10))
.caixanfnum.Text = TempSplit(0)
.caixanfdata.Text = TempSplit(1)
```

### This would be the most direct way to do this and is my preferred way.

If there are other instances of `Chr(10)` in your text box values however;

### 2. Using `Left`, `Right` and `Len` Functions (ft. [`Mid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function))

Something like;

```
.caixanfnum.Text = Left(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4), DadosLen)
.caixanfdata.Text = Right(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4), Len(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4)) - DadosLen)
```

Altenatively to the `Right` function you could use `Mid` instead:

`Mid(Sheets("-").Cells(linha, 4), DadosLen + 2`

Less preferred by me but will work.